# Move svn repository from projectLocker

Tags: svn, projectlocker

I want to move a project in projectLocker with all history.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestions:

1) Use the free svnsync tool to create a local mirror of your repository on your computer, with its history.  (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html)

2) Ask ProjectLocker to help you with this.  If you haven't already, just file a support ticket indicating that you want to move your repository from ProjectLocker.

(I work for ProjectLocker, and I'd be surprised if you've asked for help here and gotten no assistance.  If that's the case, please email me @projectlocker.com and I'll personally help.)

Comment: I opened a ticket at projectLocker

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ProjectLocker, but the website says that project owners can create a full dump of their subversion repository at any time. I'll assume that this means in the format generated by [svnadmin dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html). If that's the case, then you'll need to create a local repository and use [svnadmin load](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html) to populate it from the dump.

```
svnadmin create new.repo
svnadmin load new.repo < oldrepo.svndump
```

Answer (score 0):

I exported a repository from ProjectLocker using these instructions, linked from their website: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt.

It was very easy, though I tweaked the process slightly:

- Replaced references to the `svnsync` user with the email address I used when signing up to ProjectLocker. (Since I am on Linux, I quoted the email address with single quotes, e.g., `--username 'me@domain.com'`.)
- Replaced the recommended `pre-revprop-change` script with a simpler one without any username checks:

  ```
  !/bin/sh
  exit 0
  ```